# Event handler unbinded after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In Backbone marionette composite view, I am using following code .

```
events: {
        'click th': 'doSort',
        'click #selectAllGroups': 'allMembersSelected'
    },

    allMembersSelected: function(event) {
        var selectAll;
        if ($("#selectAllGroups").prop('checked') == true) {
            selectAll = true;
        } else {
            selectAll = false;
        }

        var allCheckboxes = document.getElementsByName("selectGroupCheckBox");
        for (var i = 0, n = allCheckboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
            allCheckboxes[i].checked = selectAll;
        }


    },
```

where #selectAllGroups is actually checkbox to select and unselect all checkboxes in the list. 
the function **allMembersSelected** is called only first time when the checkbox is clicked , it wouldn't be called on any subsequent clicks.
**One Interesting point** is that If I remove the below section from code, the click handler would be called on subsequent clicks and the issue wouldn't come.

```
if ($("#selectAllGroups").prop('checked') == true) {
    selectAll = true;
} else {
    selectAll = false;
}
```

Comment: Try `if ($("#selectAllGroups").prop('checked') == "true") {`

Comment: `==` is universal condition(it can check string or boolean). @GuruprasadRao. it is not correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update this function as:

```
allMembersSelected: function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation(); // add this one too, as seems event is bubbling up.
   $('input[type="checkbox"][name="selectGroupCheckBox"]')
                      .prop('checked', $("#selectAllGroups").prop('checked'));

},
```

It will mark `check` all the checkboxes named `"selectGroupCheckBox"` only when `#selectAllGroups` checkbox is checked.

---

This code block:

```
events: {
    'click th': 'doSort', // 2. when event comes here all the elements on the row gets replaced by new rows. 
    'click #selectAllGroups': 'allMembersSelected' // 1. click on it bubbles up to the parent th
},
```

I find it that when you click on `th` it sorts all the rows and replaces all the elements with the new ones. So all the child elements inside every `th` if they have any event bound on it that will bubble up to the dom and that would cause in sort.

Same thing is happening with your `#selectAllGroups` checkbox as it is in the `th` or i would say that should be in the `th` so any event bound on it bubbles up to the `th` which causes in sorting and it feels that event is not working on checkbox but it does.

Comment: Better syntax, but my issue is something else. I believe, after first click it's unbinding the event from event handler.

Comment: I guess you have `event.stopPropagation()` issue. is it doing sorting when you click on checkbox?

Comment: @Ahmad  seen your events object, that led me to this.

Comment: that solved my problem, you can post it as an answer and I would accept it